# <!--nextpage--> somehow causes the layout to be skewed

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm using the <!--nextpage--> function to page break and split the page on Wordpress.
The problem is, whenever <!--nextpage--> is inserted, the position of sidebar is moved to where it shouldn't be.
It's like this on page.php:

```
<div class="main">
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
...
?>
<?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
</div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

So if I understand correctly, .main and get_sidebar are on the same level.
But when I actually make some page using this template, an output is like this:

```
<div class="main">
 <div class="section">
   ...
   <div class="content">
    // pagination is inserted here
   </div>
   <aside class="sidebar">
   ...
   </aside>
 </div>
</div>
```

In other words, get_sidebar(aside tag) automatically moves into .section.
This is extremely confusing to me, and really don't know what to do here.
Why does Wordpress decide to put it inside of .section? Why can't it be faithful to the template?
Now the sidebar is positioned at the end of content instead of being on the right side.
What are the possible causes and solution to this issue?

Thank you for reading.